# temporary ad serving limit on Admob

Tags: flutter, admob

This is the 3rd time I am facing this issue without any fault of mine and every time it happens I lose revenue. I would like to know if there is any better alternative to admob in flutter which google play will accept as I am tired of this limit being imposed for which I have to wait several weeks to recover. Developers spend several months of time and energy to make great apps and to make some money and this is really sad.
Every time I build a newer app version, I even comment all my ad-related code before running it on the emulator, and then once it is ready, uncomment it and release

1. Does this happen to every developer out there?
2. Any alternative to admob in flutter acceptable by google play?

Answer (score 1):

**Many of the developers out here are facing this issue.**

You can use the following services which are considered as competitive to Google AdMobs.

> **[Amazon Publisher Services](https://aps.amazon.com/aps/solutions-for-mobile-app-developers/)** : Newest options available to mobile app developers. Since it is a newbie *(not much popular among developers)* it is not as easy to use as AdMob, but it's a very potent competitive option.
>
> **[Facebook Audience Network](https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/getting-started)** : A true rivalry to Google AdMob and considered it as a replacement to Google AdMob. Mostly loved by business peoples and market analyst to monetize their services.

Now ball is in your court and you need to take the call. If you still want to stick to the Google services then please try **[`Admob Frequency Capping`](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/4377690)** to limit the ads served to your individual user.

Comment: Thanks. I learn't that there is something called mediation. I am gonna take a look at it. It seems that we can create ad accounts for example in facebook and use it in an aggregator/mediator which can then fill up the best ads based on ecpm and this way even if admob sets the limit, others will fill it up. It would be great if there is any article/video to show detailed steps for the same as I can see mediation option in admob

Comment: So you are planning to use both AdMob and Facebook Ads ?

Comment: I dont have facebook account. I created account in Vungle and AppLovin few days ago as I had thought of using any sdk of that in my app. But now, it seems connected to mediation. So not sure how to connect those accounts to the mediation setup in admob. In Admob , under mediation, I now added the report id of those two accounts, but what next should I do to pull in ads from those networks, not sure

Comment: Are you sure that through mediation, if AdMob restricts your ads, they are filled by the other mediation ad networks? (Mine is a question, I'm curious about the answer)

Comment: well, first of all I am not sure of how mediation works or how to set it up. Regarding your question, this link says so: https://medium.com/@tigerwed/importance-of-mediation-in-the-world-ruled-by-dumb-google-bots-91708c7ce1a5